# Change datasource in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, kendo-ui

I have added demo in [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/seM2X/1/). This code works perfectly in google chrome (I didn't check with other browsers). Which means the field and datasource are perfectly replaced. But while convert it as android app using phonegap and cordova.js it works like this demo (Here the datasource is append to the previous one). I don't know what happens.

If this question didn't clear please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you simply trying to replace the data, or do you want to change the columns that are displayed?

Comment: @LarsHöppner Want to change the columns also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a current version of Kendo UI so you can use the `destroy` method, for example.
Your change handler should then look like this:

```
function changedata() {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").destroy();
    $("#grid").empty();

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: [{
            name: "Jane Doe",
            age: 30,
            no: 11
        }, {
            name: "John Doe",
            age: 33,
            no: 12
        }]
    });
}
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/eYLEM/))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about whether you want to add row or replace whole grid contents. But it will solve both the problems. You can try this.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seM2X/2/)**

**To add extra data**

```
 function changedata() {

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.add({ name: "John Doe", age: 33});
    grid.dataSource.add({ name: "Jane Doe", age: 30}

     );
  }
```

**To Replace the data.**

```
function replacedata() {
 $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data([{ name: "aaaa Doe", age: 30 },{ name: "aaaa Doe", age: 23 }]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to change the columns too.

Comment: wat do you mean by that. do you mean header or add new column.